# Is minsdk version depicts features

Tags: android

Is minsdk version is related to features?

If I set min sdk of 10, then am I restricted to using the features of API greater than 10?

Comment: What in [the official description](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html) did you find unclear?

Comment: Is there way to  use the feature of API greater than 10  & run the app in device with version 2.3.3.I have recently started learning android,sorry if my query dont make much sense

Comment: Add the **support library**, to use NEW features in OLD devices.

Comment: @DerGolem the question was more general. What you offer is how to deal with it (which is correct)...

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes.

Using minSdk means you will allow your apps to run on devices with this android version, which means you can't use functions and classes of newer APIs without any compatibility mechanism.

For example, you can't use getActionBar() on an activity, since this was introduced on API 11 .

If you do this, your app will crash on such devices.

But don't worry: Lint will usually warn you about such cases (if you have the settings right), and you also have plenty of compatibility libraries to let you use the new functions on old OS versions

Comment: Is there any way to make use of say(getActionBar()) on API less than 11 devices and application?Please dont mind if my ques dont make much sense.

Comment: Yes, as I've mentioned, there are compatibility libraries that allows you to overcome those limitations. Google has one that is called "support library", and there is also a very popular one for ActionBar support, called "ActionBarSherlock" (but it's not being updated anymore).

Comment: @Ultraviolence you can use actionbar from the support library. Use AppCompat.

Answer (score 0):

This means phones with older versions of android (2.3.2 and less) can't install the app. But you can use virtually all older features of android with a few exceptions that have been deprecated for example blur behind (WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND)